# I have table with columns like Cycle_code (2 char), cycle_month (2 char),cycle_year (4 char). how can I select last 06 cycle_month data?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

> Initials column where "where" clause is applying are like "Cycle_code" and "Cycle_month" and >"Cycle_year". I want a query which can select last 6 cycle_month data from current cycle month.but >suppose current cycle month is 04 then to find 6 months data I need to search for last year's 2 months ?>also. now in my cycle_year column "where clause" value should be changed wrt to cycle_month.
>   I tried this.

````
where cycle_code="XX" and
cycle_month in (04,03,02,01,11,12) and
cycle_year ="2020";```
````

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use arithmetic on year/month combos:

```
where cycle_year * 12 + cycle_month >= extract(year from sysdate) * 12 + extract(month from sysdate) - 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rebuild a legitimate date from these parts with `to_date()` and use it for filtering:

```
where to_date(cycle_year || '-' || cycle_month || '-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
    >=  trunc(sysdate, 'mon') - interval '6' month
```

I wouldn't actually recommend storing your dates as separate parts, since this makes things unnecessarily complicated when you need to treat them as dates. You could use a computed column to simplify the queries:

```
alter table mytable add 
    mydate as (to_date(cycle_year || '-' || cycle_month || '-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'))
```

Then you can just do:

```
where mydate >= trunc(sysdate, 'mon') - interval '6' month
```